# What is this UI Element?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is this a built in UI Element? I see it used in the address book, mail app, and other 3rd party apps but I can't find the object in Xcode anywhere... [image: What am I?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Basically, it's intended to replace what would be commonly accomplished with a Combo Box in a traditional setting.

Comment: `UIActionSheet`s are more like prompts. `UIPickerView`s are more analogous to combo boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a UIActionSheet you usually use it to present a user with a set of options for an action. You can use it to warn a user about a potentially dangerous task such as deleting something like a photo. you can read more about it here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html